# Filter API Get in Python

Tags: python, rest

I'm using Python to do some data cleaning/task automation, but am having a hard time reading in data through an API with multiple conditions. My data is as follows:

```
url =  "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/erm2-nwe9.json?descriptor='Social Distancing' or descriptor='Face Covering Violation' or descriptor='Business not in compliance'"
r = requests.get(url)
x = r.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

When I pull it, it only provides me with data where the descriptor is 'Social Distancing'.  Any tips on how to change this so that it filters for all of the needed data?

Comment: I think the `requests` module will handle this for you automatically, but make sure your URL is being properly encoded.  (e.g. spaces need to become `%20`.)

Comment: That said, I'm not sure this question is a good fit for StackOverflow since it is more about the behavior of this *specific* `data.cityofnewyork.us` API endpoint.

Comment: Why not just make 3 separate API calls with each condition, then merge that result?

Answer (score 0):

Make three requests and merge their responses:

```
    def get_data(filter):
            url =  "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/erm2-nwe9.json?descriptor='{0}'".format(filter)
            r = requests.get(url)
            return pd.DataFrame(r.json())


    df = pd.concat([
      get_data('Social Distancing'),
      get_data('Face Covering Violation'),
      get_data('Business not in compliance')

    ])
```